# Does firebase storage for android support offline cache?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I want to know whether Firebase storage for Android does support offline capabilities like firestore or not?

Comment: Can I know why downvote?

Comment: I would tend to agree with @VivekRajendran, there's this seems like a valid question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Firebase SDKs for Cloud Storage don't natively support offline access.  If you use a library such as Glide for Android, you may have some offline disk cache support, but that not part of the core Android SDK for Cloud Storage.

Comment: Thank you. Can you provide more information on how to use offline support with Glide in offline?

Answer (score -3):

**Firebase works even if your app temporarily loses its network connection. In addition, Firebase also provides tools for persisting data locally, managing presence, and handling latency.**

**You can enable disk persistence with just one line of code.**

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

**Firebase also provide below functionality:-**

- **Store Fresh Data**

  like :-

  ```
  DatabaseReference scoresRef =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("scores");
  scoresRef.keepSynced(true);
  ```
- **Querying Data Offline**
- **Handling Transactions Offline**

Comment: I only asking for Firesbase **storage** not database

Comment: Does setting FirebaseDatabase setPersistenceEnabled true also effect Cloud Storage ?

Comment: No, it affects only database